# mesh edges still slightly visible after subdividing and shading smooth

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, subdivision-surface

I am modeling a mesh in blender 2.9, and I gave it a subdivision surface modifier, then shaded it smooth.  Most of it worked great, but there are still some parts of the mesh where I can still see some edges (example below)
[image]
I do not want those edges to be visible.  Is there anything I could do to eliminate this effect?  Any help is appreciated! : )

(PS, I will give the link to my file below)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try selecting the faces with visible edges(by that I mean press alt click the face to select all the faces surrounding the top and bottom part of the object), split, then limited dissolve. You would notice a significant difference.

PS. you need to fix the topology afterwards though.

Comment: thanks, it worked like a charm.